# Upload files to SQL from a csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I had a FileUpload control earlier to upload each file individually in the database. But now I want to be able to do bulk upload.

My requirement is that a csv file contains the filename and filepath, I need to upload the csv using FileUpload and eventually run a code that reads the csv and inserts each file into a table ApplicantAttachment. ApplicantAttachment has columns fileName (NVARCHAR), FilePath(NVARCHAR), Attachment (VARBINARY). In this attachment column, I need to save the binary format of the files mentioned in the csv. 
MY CSV looks like this 
FileName    FilePath
dl-54a.pdf  c:\users\abc\desktop\dl-54a.pdf
xyz.doc     c:\users\abc\desktop\xyz.doc

I wish I could do something like this. But I know we caanot assing filename etc to the Fileupload object. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="csvFile" runat="server" Width="400" /></td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" /></td>
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (csvFile.HasFile)
        {
            List<string[]> filesToUpload = parseCSV(csvFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            SaveFiles(filesToUpload);
        }
    }

    public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
    {
        List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                string[] row;

                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!readFile.ReadLine().Contains("ApplicantId"))
                    {
                        row = line.Split(',');                            
                        parsedData.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ;
        }

        return parsedData;
    }

    private void SaveFiles(List<string[]> files)
    {
        foreach (string[] attachment in files)
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
                fu.FileName = attachment[1].ToString();
                if (fu.HasFile)
                {
                    ApplicantAttachment aa1 = new ApplicantAttachment();
                    aa1.Filename = attachment[0].ToString();
                    aa1.FileType = fu.PostedFile.ContentType;
                    aa1.Attachment = fu.FileBytes;
                    db.ApplicantAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(aa1);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you *need* to upload by using a csv file or can you just do a multiupload as discussed in this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/csharpgeneral/thread/001cf9a5-5b3a-4282-9be9-9908b32fad5b

Comment: I need to upload through csv because there are other columns in the csv and the table to which it is to be inserted to. I removed them for simplicity.

Comment: so you are uploading a file into multiple columns/tables?

Comment: Take another look at @peroija suggestion, and simply have the user include information about the file from the form itself.  It is not possible, as you appear to already know from your comment `But I know we caanot assing filename etc to the Fileupload object.`, to pull a file from the client directly.

Comment: I found the solution to my question, will have to use File.ReadAllBytes(attachment[2].ToString()) to read the binary data of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works. FileUpload cant be used.

```
     private void SaveFiles(List<string[]> files)
     {
        foreach (string[] attachment in files)
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                string path = attachment[1].ToString();
                byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                ApplicantAttachment aa1 = new ApplicantAttachment();
                aa1.Filename = attachment[0].ToString();
                aa1.FileType = MIMEType.GetType(attachment[1].ToString());
                aa1.Attachment = fileBytes;
                db.ApplicantAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(aa1);
                db.SubmitChanges();

            }
        }
     }
```